# Promote Postgres standby while materialized view updates in primary

Tags: postgresql, replication, materialized-view

I have one primary Postgres server (`serverA`) and one standby Postgres server (`serverB`), both running `Postgres 9.4` with `Streaming Replication` enabled.

Is it possible to update a materialized view on `serverA`, promote `serverB` to primary, and then once the materialized view is updated, promote `serverA` back to primary and have everything replicate correctly (the updated view to `serverB`, and any writes on serverB while it was primary back to `serverA`)?

(Also, just to note, both systems currently receive very minimal production traffic.)